# nav2 behavior tree condition plugin get parameters from yaml

Tags: navigation, plugin, nav2

ROS_DISTRO:Humble

Package: nav2_behavior_tree

#### Description

I am developing my own behavior tree *condition* plugin (inside nav2_behavior_tree package). I have defined the input port: max_heading_error. It works fine with nav2 and takes the corresponding value from the behavior tree XML.

#### Problem

As far as I know, this value has to be set in the behavior_tree.xml and I can't find a way to get the value from parameters like:

```
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    max_heading_error: 0.1
```

I have tried this way:

```
rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr client_node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("_");
this->max_heading_error_= client_node->get_parameter("max_heading_error").as_double();
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A ticket was recently filed (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3800) that points out the more general problem that this is pointing out.

If you create a node, that node is **not** the BT Navigator node that the parameter is listed under in the yaml file. Its the name you gave the node on construction. For example, you should not create your own node, but use the node provided for you on the blackboard as a shared pointer under the key "node" as other BT nodes do (e.g. look at others for example).

The issue still remains that this client node is not actually the BT Navigator-named node, so parameters under the BT Navigator namespace in the yaml file are not findable.

I'm going to work through this issue today and follow up in that ticket.